# Change placeholder style for html input type date

Tags: html, date, input, placeholder

Need to make input type date's default placeholder to look alike [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugDcI.png)

Comment: What did you try so far? A minimal reproduceble example is usually required

Comment: @alesssz so far i have just default placeholder like this (https://imgbbb.com/image/LR2vae)

Comment: that means you should post a minimal reproduceble example in the post, not the picture of the result

Comment: Here it is:  `<div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="inputDate4" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY">
          </div>
         </div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you searched for, but this is the fastest way i found to do that. 
I used this, link for reference https://help.syncfusion.com/js/datepicker/overview

```js
var datepicker = new ej.calendars.DatePicker({ width: "200px" });
datepicker.appendTo('#datepicker');
```

```css
.changeStyle {
  word-spacing: 40px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/dist/ej2.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/material.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <input id="datepicker" class="changeStyle" type="text" 
          placeholder="MM DD YYYY">

</body>

</html>
```